# How to delete file in native code passed from Java code?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-10.0

I am adjusting code of my Android app (Java + native) to Android 10 Scoped Storage changes.

I declared required permissions in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I launched ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user pick a directory.

What I do is I create file on external storage, detach file desciptor and pass to native code:

```
DocumentFile df = documentFile.createFile("text/plain", "my_file");
ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(df.getUri(), "rw");
myNativeFunction(pfd.detachFd());
```

Now, native side reads/writes from/to the file. And is responsible for closing the file descriptor.

My question is how to delete that file by native code?

Normally, in order to delete file one needs to pass pathname to it (remove(), unlink() functions take it as parameter). With Uri I failed to do that - I get "No such file or directory" error.

Thank you.

Comment: "I launched ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user pick a directory" -- no, you let the user pick a document tree. Whether that tree is represented by a directory on the filesystem of any computer in the galaxy is up to the developers of the documents provider that the user chose. "What I do is I create file on external storage" -- no, you create a document in the document tree. "My question is how to delete that file by native code?" -- there is no file. However, you can arrange for your native code to call `delete()` on your `DocumentFile`.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, choosen document tree can be anywhere. And, regarding file - I actually create a file under choosen document tree and pass its descriptor to native side. "However, you can arrange for your native code to call delete() on your DocumentFile" - will try that one, thanks.

Comment: I tried calling delete() on DocumentFile object in native code and it works!! Thank you again.

Comment: Since calling `delete()` from native code is a bit unusual, it would be great if you could post an answer to your own question, showing what you wound up using. Regardless, I am glad to hear that it is working for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) I realized that I need to re-think my app design.
So, for this case I decided to keep all the code operating on DocumentFile(s) at the Java side (including deletion) and read/write from/to files using read()/write() C functions at native side (using file descriptors previously detached from Java). In my case it is actually like that:

1. Android app:

   - launch ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to pick document tree and pass corresponding tree Uri to my Android AAR library
   - request AAR library for deletion of files under tree Uri
2. AAR library (Java + native):

   - create DocumentFile object from passed tree Uri
   - create DocumentFile(s) under Document tree and pass file descriptors to native code (App does not have to know anything about actual files)
   - delete DocumentFile(s)